# Extract Data from 2 columns if it matches condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, regexextract, copy-paste

This is how my main data sheet looks like

[image]

And for any item that has customization, for e.g. **- ORGANIC**, I want to extract/copy just those data, the meal name & total units to another sheet.
And then transpose them.

Partial answer to my question:

```
=INDEX(A2:B17,MATCH(G9&"*-*",A2:A17,))
```

However this only brings up 1 row, not all matches.

Using that with FILTER, same result:

```
=FILTER(A2:B17,A2:A17=INDEX(A2:A17,MATCH("M01"&"*-*",A2:A17,)))
```

**Works but now I have no clue how to drag this down. To find other values.**

Here is my sample sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cAGa-Mc6KQjrTjwe8OM58wHbABDxI4toEbYOIs8_9VE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No this was not a simple yes or no question, the one about macros was. You took that one in the wrong manner. Since you seem more bent on saying I'm freeloading, here's my (embarrassing) effort of 2 days:
=TRANSPOSE(A2:B17)
=FILTER(A2:B17,MATCH(A2*,A2:A17,0))
=MATCH("A2*",A2:B10,0)
=QUERY(A2:B17, "SELECT * where A="A2"&"*")")
Basically I can't connect any of them together to get even close to what I have in mind.

Comment: Sorry Erik, I didn't mean to be rude. But I've been working on this thing for a long time, and just running around in circles. My last resort is this. Its not that I haven't tried, nothing is even embarassingly close to the answer.

Comment: BUT thanks to my other question and answers to that, my most recent attempt did bring me close,=INDEX(query(IMPORTRANGE($I$2,"Custom Labels!A2:B"),"select Col1, Col2",0),MATCH("K01"&"*- *",IMPORTRANGE($I$2,"Custom Labels!A2:A"),0)),  THEN =TRANSPOSE(FORMULA). Works but now I have no clue how to drag this down.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer to this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:B17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G9&"* - *",A2:A17))))
```